# Laravel API, Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: jquery, laravel, api, authorization, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel API using Laravel Passport (OAuth2 with password grant). When I access an endpoint with Postman, it responds correctly. When I try to access with jQuery, I get this error:

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Comment: did you add `Authorization` in `CORS` allow header section ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your Laravel setup? You need to add CORS on your Laravel end.

Some usefull resources:

https://learninglaravel.net/laravel-51-easily-enable-cors

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors